# Overwrite file using AWK in a for loop

Tags: awk, grep, scripting, expect

I'm working on the following script:

```
!/bin/bash
FILE1=dispositivoss.csv
NUMERODISP="$(wc -l $FILE1 | awk '{print $1}')"    

for (( c=2; c<=$NUMERODISP; c++ ))
do  
   IP=$(awk -vnum="$c" 'NR == num { print $NF }' dispositivoss.csv)
    expect -f conexionindividual.sh $IP
    SN=$(grep "System serial number" SN_$IP.dat | sed 's/^.*: //')  
    awk -v "ln=$c" -v "sn=$SN" '{print (NR==ln) ? $0","sn : $0;}' <dispositivoss.csv
done
```

The script takes the number of lines in a file called "dispositivos.csv"

Based on that goes through a for loop in wich it takes an IP address and connect via telnet to that IP.

Then, type "show version" save the output in a file

Using grep it takes the "System serial number" and add it to "dispositivos.csv" in its respective line using awk.

this is conexionindividual.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set Username "user" 
set Password "password"
set IP   [lindex $argv 0];
spawn ssh -p 22 cesar@localhost
expect "*?"
send "yes\r"
expect "password: "
send "mycomputerpass\r"
expect "$ "
send "telnet $IP\r"
expect "Username:"
send "$Username\r"
expect "Password: "
send "$Password\r"
expect "*>"
send "show version\r"
log_file -noappend SN_$IP.dat;
expect -ex "--More--" {send -- " "; exp_continue}
expect "*>"
log_file;
expect "*>"
send "exit\r"
```

Everything goes well but the last part, in each iteration the output is like this:

```
 telnet 148.000.000.253
Trying 148.000.000.253...
Connected to 148.000.000.253.
Escape character is '^]'.

DCyTIC BUAP Solo Usuarios Autorizados. Usuario: user
Password: 

Ingenieria_Posgrado>show version
Cisco IOS Software, C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASE-M), Version 12.2(25)SEE3, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
Copyright (c) 1986-2007 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Thu 22-Feb-07 13:57 by myl
Image text-base: 0x00003000, data-base: 0x00AA3380

ROM: Bootstrap program is C2960 boot loader
BOOTLDR: C2960 Boot Loader (C2960-HBOOT-M) Version 12.2(25r)SEE1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

Ingenieria_Posgrado uptime is 19 weeks, 4 days, 20 hours, 8 minutes
System returned to ROM by power-on
System restarted at 14:49:42 gmt Sat Nov 5 2016
System image file is "flash:c2960-lanbase-mz.122-25.SEE3/c2960-lanbase-mz.122-25.SEE3.bin"

cisco WS-C2960-24TC-L (PowerPC405) processor (revision E0) with 61440K/4088K bytes of memory.
Processor board ID FOC1128W4DD
Last reset from power-on
1 Virtual Ethernet interface
24 FastEthernet interfaces
2 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces
The password-recovery mechanism is enabled.

64K bytes of flash-simulated non-volatile configuration memory.
Base ethernet MAC Address       : 00:1C:F9:AA:52:00
Motherboard assembly number     : 73-9832-07
Power supply part number        : 341-0097-02
Motherboard serial number       : FOC1128255N
Power supply serial number      : AZS1128084Q
Model revision number           : E0
Motherboard revision number     : A0
Model number                    : WS-C2960-24TC-L
System serial number            : FOC1128W4DD # HERE WE HAVE THE SN
Top Assembly Part Number        : 800-26671-03
Top Assembly Revision Number    : A0
Version ID                      : V03
CLEI Code Number                : COM3K00BRB
Hardware Board Revision Number  : 0x01


Switch   Ports  Model              SW Version              SW Image            
------   -----  -----              ----------              ----------          
*    1   26     WS-C2960-24TC-L    12.2(25)SEE3            C2960-LANBASE-M     


Configuration register is 0xF

Ingenieria_Posgrado>device_id,ip_address
 BIOTERIO, 148.000.00.189                  #this is dispositivoss.csv
 N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL), 148.000.0.192
 LAB_PESADO, 148.000.000.130
 Arquitectura_Salones, 148.000.000.61
 CIVIL_253, 148.000.000.253
 Arquitectura, 148.000.000.253
 ING_CIVIL, 148.000.000.251
 ING_CIVIL_DIR, 148.000.0.188
 Ingenieria_Posgrado, 148.000.000.253,FOC1128W4DD  #HERE IT IS
 Biblio_Barragan, 148.000.000.61
 Electronica_Edif_3, 148.000.000.253
spawn ssh -p 22 cesar@localhost
cesar@localhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
cesar@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-108-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

206 packages can be updated.
119 updates are security updates.

New release '16.04.2 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.

Last login: Thu Mar 23 11:00:39 2017 from localhost
```

It does the job but it is printed just in the terminal, once the script finish if I check dispositivoss.csv nothing changes. like this:

```
device_id,ip_address
 BIOTERIO, 148.000.00.189
 N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL), 148.000.0.192
 LAB_PESADO, 148.000.000.130
 Arquitectura_Salones, 148.000.000.61
 CIVIL_253, 148.000.000.253
 Arquitectura, 148.000.000.253
 ING_CIVIL, 148.000.000.251
 ING_CIVIL_DIR, 148.000.0.188
 Ingenieria_Posgrado, 148.000.000.253
 Biblio_Barragan, 148.000.000.61
 Electronica_Edif_3, 148.000.000.253
```

I Know the problem is with awk.
I would like to keep the SN in the same file.
those are the tries I've done:

awk -v "ln=$c" -v "sn=$SN" '{print (NR==ln) ? $0","sn : $0;}' dispositivoss.cvs

```
awk -v "ln=$c" -v "sn=$SN" '{print (NR==ln) ? $0","sn : $0;}' dispositivoss.cvs>dispositivosfinal.csv

awk -v "ln=$c" -v "sn=$SN" '{print (NR==ln) ? $0","sn : $0;}' dispositivoss.cvs

awk -v "ln=$c" -v "sn=$SN" '{print (NR==ln) ? $0","sn : $0;}' dispositivosfinal.csv<dispositivoss.cvs   

awk -v "ln=$c" -v "sn=$SN" '{print (NR==ln) ? $0","sn : $0;}'<<dispositivoss.cvs
```

SOLVED:

```
awk -v "ln=$c" -v "sn=$SN" '{print (NR==ln) ? $0","sn : $0;}' dispositivoss.csv>dispositivosfinal.csv   
mv dispositivosfinal.csv dispositivoss.csv
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer, but I am curious why you switch back and forth between `awk 'stuff' file` and `awk 'stuff' < file`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question, you wonder why your input file, `dispositivoss.csv` does not change. I suspect you think that `awk`'s `print` command modifies the input file, but this is not the case.

I suggest trying something along these lines:

```
for IP in $(awk 'NR > 1 { print $NF }' dispositivoss.csv)
    do expect -f conexionindividual.sh $IP
done | awk 'BEGIN { print } /System serial number/ { print $NF }' > temp_file
paste -d, dispositivoss.csv temp_file
```

Comment: That's right,  How can I modify the input file in each iteration?